# Fisher's exact test for gene count data

Tags: r, matrix, count

I am trying to apply Fisher's exact test in R for a matrix which contains count data for a TCR-seq dataset. Each row in the matrix is a different tcr clonotype and each column represents different conditions. The cells have counts for each tcr for each condition. I want to apply fisher's exact test to test each tcr against rest of the tcr to test null hypothesis that they are not different between conditions.

I am looking for a solution similar to the following line of code that iterates over the full matrix and provides me with a p-value.

```
`apply(tab, 1, function(x) fisher.test(matrix(x,nrow=2,ncol=2))$p.value)`
```

Here is a small example containing few clonotypes and their counts:

[clonotype counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBD1X.png)

How do I set this up in R?Any suggestions are welcome.

This is similar to the question that has been asked below (but in the context of gene expression).

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201586/fishers-exact-test-in-rna-seq?newreg=6c8ab398c53c425ebc2f7e380a3cb15c

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we need to see (a sample of) your data.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that Fisher's Exact Test is only exact when both margins of the table are known *a priori*.  This is rarely the case, and so there may be better options available.

Comment: Thanks Limey. I have posted an example containing few tcr and their counts

Comment: The data you posted are not count data. Normalized?

Comment: Hi jblood94. They are normalized based on total read count for the sample. This is to account for differences in total read count across samples.

Comment: So, each column of the full data set should add to 1?

Comment: Yes this is correct

Comment: This might give you some ideas: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MADPop/vignettes/MADPop-quicktut.html